# how to load springconfiguration xml inside web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

How to load bean and inject bean from my applicaationContext to My Controller using web.xml.. im trying to add context-param and load applicationContext.xml inside web.xml but it does'nt work.. when i put mahasiswa bean inside DispatcherServlet, it works..

My Controller :

```
@Autowired private Mahasiswa mhs;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String Home(){
    mhs.tampilkan();
    return "index";
}
```

My Mahasiswa :

```
private String nama;

public String getNama() {
    return nama;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
    this.nama = nama;
}

public void tampilkan(){
    System.out.println(this.nama);
}
```

web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DispatcherServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.belajar.spring.controller">
</context:component-scan>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="mahasiswa" class="com.belajar.spring.controller.Mahasiswa">
    <property name="nama" value="Dwi"></property>
</bean>
```

[SS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4lfR.png)

Comment: On which location you have placed your DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml file ?

Comment: inside /WEB-INF https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4lfR.png

Comment: Did it solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing code in web.xml for the custom application context with the below code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: can you copy paste your entire web.xml ?